# Alternate table Row Color in HTML/CSS for Easy User Experience?

Tags: html, css, sqlite, flask, datatables

I am 100% the code outside of what I am posting is correct. It is my understanding of HTML/CSS tables that is causing my issue. For a table with (x) number of rows, when using the following format, How do I ensure every other line is printed gray-white-gray-white, ad infinitum.

I am also aware that the code Im posting only causes the data to be printed twice for each row, it is the closest I could figure myself, for the time being.

```
  <table style='margin:auto;text-align: center;'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="white_head">Name</th>
                    <th class="black_head">Retail Price</th>
                    <th class="white_head">Avg Purchase Cost</th>
                    <th class="black_head">Quantity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            
            {% for artwork in artwork_inventory %}
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="black">{{ artwork.name }}</td>
                    <td class="white">{{ artwork.currentprice }}</td>
                    <td class="black">{{ artwork.averageCost }}</td>
                    <td class="white">{{ artwork.onHandQuantity }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="white">{{ artwork.name }}</td>
                    <td class="black">{{ artwork.currentprice }}</td>
                    <td class="white">{{ artwork.averageCost }}</td>
                    <td class="black">{{ artwork.onHandQuantity }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Have you investigated :nth-child(odd) and :nth-child(even)?

Comment: I have, but I havent found where the documentation is. It looks like you would use it something like this.
for table data:
td.nth-child(odd){
     color: black;
}

<td> {{ table.data }} </td>

This does not seem to work for me though.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child and be careful to distinguish between dots and colons. And are you not wanting every other row to be colored differently?

Comment: I want every other row a different color such as this:

NAME    OTHER INFO     MORE INFO     MORE INFO
black  black  black  black  black  black  black  black
white  white  white  white  white  white  white  white
black  black  black  black  black  black  black  black
ad infinitum.

When printed though, because I only have one row listed for columns labels and then one for the loop, every row is being identified as odd when I write it as above

Comment: It's possible that I'm confused because maybe you are talking about whether the table is getting printed with alternating row colors. Is that right? To get background colors printed you probably have to tell your browser that it is to do that. Could you clarify whether the problem is physically printing it (on paper) or viewing it on a screen.

Comment: Is your tbody in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nth-child(odd) pseudo class selector in CSS.

You want the first row of the tbody to have a gray background then the next one a white one then the next one gray and so on.

So you can select this way:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #eeeeee; }
tbody tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #ffffff; }
```

Here's an HTML/CSS snippet to show the idea.

```css
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table style='margin:auto;text-align: center;'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="white_head">Name</th>
      <th class="black_head">Retail Price</th>
      <th class="white_head">Avg Purchase Cost</th>
      <th class="black_head">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <!--{% for artwork in artwork_inventory %} -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="black">{{ artwork.name }}</td>
      <td class="white">{{ artwork.currentprice }}</td>
      <td class="black">{{ artwork.averageCost }}</td>
      <td class="white">{{ artwork.onHandQuantity }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="white">{{ artwork.name }}</td>
      <td class="black">{{ artwork.currentprice }}</td>
      <td class="white">{{ artwork.averageCost }}</td>
      <td class="black">{{ artwork.onHandQuantity }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="black">{{ artwork.name }}</td>
      <td class="white">{{ artwork.currentprice }}</td>
      <td class="black">{{ artwork.averageCost }}</td>
      <td class="white">{{ artwork.onHandQuantity }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="white">{{ artwork.name }}</td>
      <td class="black">{{ artwork.currentprice }}</td>
      <td class="white">{{ artwork.averageCost }}</td>
      <td class="black">{{ artwork.onHandQuantity }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="black">{{ artwork.name }}</td>
      <td class="white">{{ artwork.currentprice }}</td>
      <td class="black">{{ artwork.averageCost }}</td>
      <td class="white">{{ artwork.onHandQuantity }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="white">{{ artwork.name }}</td>
      <td class="black">{{ artwork.currentprice }}</td>
      <td class="white">{{ artwork.averageCost }}</td>
      <td class="black">{{ artwork.onHandQuantity }}</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- {% endfor %} -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Incidentally in your code be careful where you put the tbody, it looks as though it will be repeated for every pair of rows you are outputting.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding another value such as artwork.id

Then do an if statement inside the for loop

```
{% for artwork in artworks_inventory %}

{% if artwork.id % 2 == 0 %}

                <tr>
                    <td class="black">{{ artwork.name }}</td>
                    <td class="white">{{ artwork.currentprice }}</td>
                    <td class="black">{{ artwork.averageCost }}</td>
                    <td class="white">{{ artwork.onHandQuantity }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="white">{{ artwork.name }}</td>
                    <td class="black">{{ artwork.currentprice }}</td>
                    <td class="white">{{ artwork.averageCost }}</td>
                    <td class="black">{{ artwork.onHandQuantity }}</td>
                </tr>
            

{% else %}


                <tr>
                    <td class="white">{{ artwork.name }}</td>
                    <td class="black">{{ artwork.currentprice }}</td>
                    <td class="white">{{ artwork.averageCost }}</td>
                    <td class="black">{{ artwork.onHandQuantity }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="white">{{ artwork.name }}</td>
                    <td class="black">{{ artwork.currentprice }}</td>
                    <td class="white">{{ artwork.averageCost }}</td>
                    <td class="black">{{ artwork.onHandQuantity }}</td>
                </tr>
            


{% endif %}



{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I already have an idea for artwork, so much appreciated. I will use this and see if this helps at all

Comment: At the risk of seeming completely helpless, I will ask how I am coding the starts with black and starts with white? With <style> tabs?

Comment: I edited my answer, can you check if it would give it your desired output